# Не обновляется страница при добавление нового элемента

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день.
Есть модель restype. Отрисовываю на странице index списком все записи и создаю форму для добавления новой записи.

```
<h1> Restype </h1>
<ul id="restype">
  <% @restypes.each do |restype| %>
      <%= render restype %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= form_for(Restype.new, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
    <p>Название</p> <%= f.text_field :name %></br>
    <p><%= f.submit "Сохранить" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Код контроллера:

```
 def create
    @restype = Restype.new(restype_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @restype.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restypes, notice: 'restype was successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

код в _restype.html.erb

```
<li><%= restype.name %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restype_path(restype) %>
</li>
```

код в create.js.erb

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @restype) %>").appendTo("#restypes");
```

После добавления новой записи, страница index не обновляется, а запись добавляется (если нажать F5, то можно будет увидеть добавленную запись). Также если после добавления открыть код страницы, то новая запись есть.
В чем может быть дело? По-моему все дела верно вот отсюда - http://rusrails.ru/working-with-javascript-in-rails.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Rail 4

Comment: Возможно, я мало информации выложил или что-то нужно уточнить в вопросе? Или очень нестандартная ситуация?

Comment: Если запись есть в коде страницы, значит она есть и на странице. Почему её не видно -- вопрос отдельный, но её наличие доказывает, что проблема не в форме.

Comment: Risto, cпасибо за информацию. А что можно дальше проверить? Чтобы лучше проблему идентифицировать.

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову -- стили. Может добавленный элемент просто скрыт со страницы или невидим за другими? Откройте на странице инспектор браузера и проверьте, где расположен ваш добавленный элемент.

Comment: Risco, возможно я не верно идентифицировал поведение системы. Использую хром. Если после добавления элемента нажать "посмотреть код страницы", то новый элемент отображается, а если посмотреть "код элемента" (как я понимаю он и есть "инспектор"), то элемента нового нет. Как я понимаю, все-таки не приходит элемент после добавления.

Comment: @lirikk12, обычно это звучит как:
* Инспектировать элемент (FireBug)
* Проверить элемент (Google Chorome)
* Исследовать элемент (Firefox)
* Проинспектировать элемент (Opera)

Находите элемент в дереве и выделяете. Браузер должен подсветить его границы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменив код в файле create.js.erb на:
$("#restype").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@restype)) %>");
все заработало. Почему?